# Why doesn't python log exceptions to syslog (but then, it does?)

Tags: python, logging, syslog, rsyslog

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SysLogHandler.emit) for the `emit()` function of Python 2.x [SysLogHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler) says:

> The record is formatted, and then sent to the syslog server. If
>   exception information is present, it is not sent to the server.

...why? The [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/handlers.py#l637) doesn't [tell](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e8783c581928/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l654) me much. Did I miss something?

However, when I try the following code:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler

rootlogger = logging.getLogger()
rootlogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
syslogh = SysLogHandler('/dev/log')
rootlogger.addHandler(syslogh)
# to see what's happening too
consoleh = logging.StreamHandler()
rootlogger.addHandler(consoleh)

# this appears in the log
rootlogger.info('foobar')
try:
    a = 42
    a / 0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    rootlogger.exception('myException!: {}'.format(e))
```

It does write the following to syslog:

> May  7 16:25:59 localhost foobar
>   May  7 16:25:54 localhost myException!: integer division or modulo by
>   zero#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "syslogonly.py",
>   line 16, in #012    a / 0#012ZeroDivisionError: integer
>   division or modulo by zero

I am using rsyslog 8.4.2 on a Debian wheezy system.

Also, I am aware there are issues with multiline, but is this related?

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `Logger.emit()`. You're calling `Logger.exception()`, which according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception), always adds exception info to the message:

> Logs a message with level ERROR on this logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug(), except that any passed exc_info is not inspected. Exception info is always added to the logging message. This method should only be called from an exception handler.

I didn't dive into the source code to determine what calls `emit()` and under what circumstances, however.

Comment: Good point. However I'm still unsure why sysloghandler shoulnd't log exceptions. Maybe it's an error in the docs?